# .getValues() in Google Script returns non-array object - results in "TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined."

Tags: google-apps-script, typeerror

The symptom that indicates I have a problem is the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined.` and the error is attached to a line that's an if statement inside a for loop.  It seems to me that the issue is in the first few lines of code, so that's what I'll put here.  I'll put the full script at the end.

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var controlRoomSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master Doc");
  var urls = controlRoomSheet.getRange(1,2,50,3).getValues();
  for(var i = 3; i < urls.length + 3; i ++){
    if(urls[i][0].slice(0, 3) == "1st" && urls[i-3][1] == null || urls[i-3][1] == "MISSING FACILITY NAME"){
      urls[i-3][1] = "MISSING FACILITY NAME";
```

To find the problem, I used google's logger.log command to look at the contents.  `urls` isn't showing up as an array, its just all the values that should be in that array in separated by a comma, that's it.

I wrote a separate script that does just three things, opens the document, gets the page by name, and retrieves the contents of first a single cell, and then the entire range.  Checked the results in Logger.log, works fine.  I then moved the same code back in to my script, and bam, it breaks.

I've recreated the setup [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GTjwIxxRKBNUuXu_HlgpkGxgwCBeOoeHipHw1N9Xrkg/edit#gid=0).

If you need the rest of the code, here is the full script.

```
function createDocAndFirstTab(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var controlRoomSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master Doc");
  var urls = controlRoomSheet.getRange(1,2,50,3).getValues();
  for(var i = 3; i < urls.length + 3; i ++){
    if(urls[i][0].slice(0, 3) == "1st" && urls[i-3][1] == null || urls[i-3][1] == "MISSING FACILITY NAME"){
      urls[i-3][1] = "MISSING FACILITY NAME";
    }
    else if(urls[i][0].slice(0, 3) == "1st" && urls[i][0].slice(0, 5) == "https" && urls[i][2] != "Yes"){
      var newDoc = urls[i-3][1];
      var newSS = SpreadsheetApp.create('newDoc');
      newSS.rename(urls[i-3][1]);
      var newDocUrl = urls[i][1];
      var sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(newDocUrl);
      var allSourceTabs = sourceSS.getSheets();
      var sourceTab = allSourceTabs[0];
      sourceTab.copyTo(newSS);
      var newSSTabs = newSS.getSheets();
      var rawRoster1 = newSSTabs[1];
      rawRoster1.setName("Roster");
      urls[i-2][1] = newSS.getUrl();
      urls[i][2] = "Yes";
      //. before closing out the creation of this file, place it in the correct folder (and make sure that folder exists!)
      DriveApp.searchFolders(controlRoomSheet.getRange('C1').getValues());
    }
  }
  controlRoomSheet.getRange(1,2,controlRoomSheet.getLastRow(),3).setValues(urls);
}
```

Comment: `i < urls.length + 3;` why?

Comment: Because you are accessing an index 3 which doesn't exist in array. Your array is [ [], [], [] ], you should use **urls[0][i]**, because there is no urls[1] nor urls[2] nor urls[3], only **urls[0]**

Comment: You failed to update all instances of `[i]` to/from `[i-3]` Make your life simple and reduce the level of indexing you need to do. Use the `Array.forEach` and `Array#map` class methods to work on the elements of an array with a callback, especially when you never need to use `break` or `continue`... (And if you do then there's `Array#filter` to call first.)

Comment: @Jeff not true. If `urls` is `[[],[],[]]`, Indexes 0, 1, 2 exist and are valid: `urls[0]`,`urls[1]` and `urls[2]` are valid. The  issue is `i` will exceed `urls.length` and therefore `urls[i]` will be `undefined` for any `i` at or above ``urls.length``

Comment: @TheMaster ```i < urls.length + 3;``` I think you make a good point.  I did it because the loop starts at index 3 and I wanted to make sure I get to the end (if I'm looking back three positions), if I don't 'overshoot' the array length, I wouldn't inspect the last three elements.  But it seems that's not necessary.
Thank you for your clarification commenting on @JeffRush 
@tehhowch I'll try those class methods.  I'm a newbie at javascript and I'm learning.  Thanks all!

Comment: But if you overshoot,  here:`urls[i][0].slice(0, 3) ==` If length is 3, when `i` becomes 4, `urls[4]` will be `undefined`. `urls[4][0]`=>`undefined[0]`=>Cannot read property "0" from undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Question

> Why I am getting an error "Cannot read property ”0“ from undefined"

## Answer

On **line 5** you are using

`i < urls.length + 3;` it calls for undefined index, so instead you can use

`i < urls.length;`

## Final code

```js
function createDocAndFirstTab(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var controlRoomSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master Doc");
  var urls = controlRoomSheet.getRange(1,2,50,3).getValues();

  for(var i = 3; i < urls.length; i++){

    if(urls[i][0].slice(0, 3) == "1st" && urls[i-3][1] == null || urls[i-3][1] == "MISSING FACILITY NAME"){

      urls[i-3][1] = "MISSING FACILITY NAME";

    }else if(urls[i][0].slice(0, 3) == "1st" && urls[i][0].slice(0, 5) == "https" && urls[i][2] != "Yes"){

      var newDoc = urls[i-3][1];
      var newSS = SpreadsheetApp.create('newDoc');
      newSS.rename(urls[i-3][1]);

      var newDocUrl = urls[i][1];
      var sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(newDocUrl);
      var allSourceTabs = sourceSS.getSheets();
      var sourceTab = allSourceTabs[0];
      sourceTab.copyTo(newSS);

      var newSSTabs = newSS.getSheets();
      var rawRoster1 = newSSTabs[1];
      rawRoster1.setName("Roster");

      urls[i-2][1] = newSS.getUrl();
      urls[i][2] = "Yes";

      //. before closing out the creation of this file, place it in the correct folder (and make sure that folder exists!)
      DriveApp.searchFolders(controlRoomSheet.getRange('C1').getValues());

    }
  }

 controlRoomSheet.getRange(1,2,urls.length,3).setValues(urls);

}
```